# Как проверить наличие записи по двум полям и если есть обновить, а если нет - добавить?

Tags: mysql, база-данных

[image: таблица]

мне надо

```
UPDATE Marks SET mark='$mark' WHERE studentid='$students[id]' AND lessonid='$lessonid'
```

а если нету записи в таблице `Marks`, то добавить

Comment: ON DUPLICATE KEY тут нет ключа или не понимаю как применить

Comment: @Visman Не совсем. Читайте первый коментарий автора.

Comment: @E_p, сравним два наших одинаковых ответа на эти разные вопросы? ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если правильно понял:

Добавить ключ на `studentid` и `lessonid`

> ALTER TABLE 
>       `table_name` 
>   ADD UNIQUE 
>      `unique_index`(`studentid`, `lessonid`);

а потом ON DUPLICATE KEY

Другой вариант сначала сделать `select`

Comment: спасибо то что надо

Answer (score 4):

Сначала нужно добавить индекс:

```
ALTER TABLE `Marks` ADD UNIQUE INDEX (`studentid`, `lessonid`);
```

Затем можно пользоваться `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE`

```
INSERT INTO `Marks` (`studentid`, `lessonid`, `mark`) VALUE (
  '$students[id]',
  '$lessonid',
  '$mark'
) 
ON DUPLICATE KEY 
UPDATE 
  mark = '$mark';
```

Comment: А зачем оставлять ответ после того, как точно такой же был принят? При этом ни какой новой/полезной информации не добавлено.

Comment: Написал часть ответа, отошел. Пришел, дописал и отправил. До этого ответа не видел. Такое бывает. Надеюсь не сильно вас этим задел )